# HtmlUnit parses "http://www.ean-search.org/sitemap.html" with 404 return

Tags: http-status-code-404, htmlunit

I'm trying to get and parse the page "http://www.ean-search.org/sitemap.html", but it always got 404 error and empty page. All the text content area are blank.

I tried many options configuration of HtmlUnit webclient, e.g. .setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false), setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true), setRedirectEnabled(false), setJavaScriptEnabled(true), setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false). 
None of them worked...

Anyone have any suggestion? Thanks.

ps: my webclient code:

```
myWebClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6); 
myWebClient.setIncorrectnessListener(new CustomizedInconnectnessListener());
myWebClient.setTimeout(180000); //3 min, used twice, first for connection, second for retrieval
try {
    myWebClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "cannot set UseInsecureSSL for BNP webclient",ex);
            //ignore it, continue
}

myWebClient.setRedirectEnabled(true); 
myWebClient.setCssEnabled(false); 
myWebClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(30000); //timeout for executing java script
myWebClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

HtmlPage htmlpage = (HtmlPage) myWebClient.getHtmlPage("http://www.ean-search.org/sitemap.html");
myWebClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(3000);
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println(htmlpage.asXml());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code you're using looks really bad. I got many errors and warnings... it is not even possible to compile it. Eg `myWebClient.getHtmlPage` should be `myWebClient.getPage`.

This code works for me and outputs the content of the page:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
HtmlPage page = myWebClient.getPage("http://www.ean-search.org/sitemap.html");
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Make sure you use the latest HtmlUnit libraries and also pay attention to the compiler when it tells you that something is deprectated. It is not advised to use those method and fields.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that those are just code snippet, and the method '.getHtmlPage' is a in-house implementation by myself. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As to using the latest HtmlUnit lib, that's very difficult sometimes due to interdependence between components. You should understand it if you have such experience in some big projects with massive lib, interface, and dependency. Of course, I will try to use the latest version of HtmlUnit. Thanks for the advice.